# Rank elements based off two variables

Tags: excel, rank

I want to rank all the entities in a list based of two variables (both percentages). One of the variables is 'the bigger the better' (x) and the other is 'smaller the better' (y). What is the best way to give each entity a score in order to rank them?

I tried doing x*(1-y) but as some of the y values are over 1, the negatives it created caused some errors.

Below is the data:

```
    x   y
a   0.953882755 0.926422663
b   0.757267676 0.926967001
c   1   1.01607838
d   0.89805254  1.008814817
e   0.672989727 0.932579014
f   0.643306278 0.924523932
g   0.621091809 0.935122957
h   0.56891321  0.918181342
i   0.563662125 0.924102288
j   0.579410248 0.946421415
k   0.781299906 1.040418561
l   0.490013047 0.920900829
m   0.475050754 0.932586282
n   0.505211144 0.972570665
o   0.566582462 1.009732948
p   0.610994363 1.031047605
q   0.686065983 1.060742126
r   0.47642017  0.983301498
s   0.463552006 0.976645044
t   0.551532341 1.025816246
u   0.478092524 1.012675037
v   0.645790431 1.084143812
w   0.390365014 1.189518019
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways : averaged ranking OR sort by distance from min&max

average ranking :

use `=RANK.AVG()` on X & Y separately. Get the average, then rank again base on the average.

sort by distance from min&max :

do '=(B2-MIN(B:B)) + (MAX(C:C)-C2)' and drag downwards. Then use `=RANK.AVG()` on the results, being the smaller (the distance from min/max) the better.

Hope it solves.